# Split string by chars which not inside specific boundary

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to write a regular expression which splits string by commas which are not inside ( ).

Examples:

```
"test,test,test".split(/.../) => var a = ["test", "test", "test"];
"test(123,345),test".split(/.../) => var a = ["test(123,345)", "test"];
"test(123,345),a(b,c)".split(/.../) => var a = ["test(123,345)", "a(b,c)"];
"test(cb(a,b),345),a(b(d,e,f),c),abc".split(/.../) => var a = ["test(cb(a,b),345)", "a(b(d,e,f),c)", "abc"];
```

I have the following regular expression, but it only works if I do not have () after the first match comma:

```
"test,test,test".split(/,(?!.*\))/) => OK
"test(cb(a,b),345),test,test".split(/,(?!.*\))/) => OK
"test,test(cb(a,b),345),test".split(/,(?!.*\))/) => FAIL
```

Comment: Maybe `/,(?![^,]*\))/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions aren't adapted to this kind of task. I think it'd be easier to roll your own parser where you follow the level of bracket-nesting to determine if you should split or not :

```
function splitTokens(var input) {
    var tokens = [];
    var currentToken = "";
    var nestingLevel = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var currentChar = input[i];
        if (currentChar === "," && nestingLevel === 0) {
            tokens.push(currentToken);
            currentToken="";
        } else {
            currentToken+=currentChar;
            if (currentChar === "(") { nestingLevel++; }
            else if (currentChar === ")") { nestingLevel--; }
        }
    }

    if (currentToken.length) {
        tokens.push(currentToken);
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

Note that I didn't handle mismatched brackets, you might want to add logic for these cases.